# Using list name as nth0 argument in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to use list name as nth0 function argument, which should give me nth element,
for example:

```
nth0(2,[1,2,3],X).
X = 3.
```

defined list:

```
L = [1,2,3].
nth0(2,L,X).
```

I want it to return X = 3. it returns random numbers in L, ̀**L = [_10614, _10620, X|_10628].**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are somehow running these two instructions at different times.

If you run them as a joint expression:

```
L = [1,2,3], nth0(2,L,X).
```

You should get the right answer.